Permanently disable built-in MX450 in Dell Latitude 5520?
My company laptop has a built-in MX450 and I just got a external GPU (4080 Super) for some demanding software we use.
Problem is, that according to the device manager, there are not enough resources to run both GPUs at the same time. So at the moment, whenever I want to use the external GPU I have to go to the device manager and disable the internal MX450. This needs to be done each restart of the laptop, so far I have not found a way to permanently disable the internal GPU. I have searched the BIOS as well as the Nvidia control panel but no luck so far.
I really don't need the MX450 (laptop also has Intel integrated GPU for normal office stuff, and otherwise I need to use the big external one anyway), so I wonder if there is any way to permanently disable it without actually removing the hardware?
Edit - Additional Information:
As requested in the comments, here more information about the error. When the problem appears, the 4080 is marked with an exclamation mark:

The device status is the following:

This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code 12)
If you want to use this device, you will need to disable one of the other devices on this system.

Going into Properties->Events I get the following message for `Device install requested:

Device PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_2702&SUBSYS_51111462&REV_A1\6&8763678&0&00080038 requires further installation.
The other two events (Driver service added) conclude with status 0.

To make things a bit more complicated: I now think the problem doesn't appear always. I am pretty sure I can reproduce it when directly restarting windows or hot-swap. Connecting the eGPU, turning its power supply on an then starting the laptop seems to work (at least sometimes).

You can't remove the MX450 as it is soldered into the motherboard. What is the exact message you are being shown when there are not enough resources?

@Ramhound I will have to look it up again, will report back here tomorrow when I am back in office.

@Ramhound I have edited the question with additional information.

In addition it seems to be a case of order: If the error appears, and I manually disable the MX450 in the device manager, the 4080 super will work. If I then enable the MX450 again, both GPUs will work.
